# Kotlin Function Literal with Receiver and chained methods

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to wrap my head around Function Literals in Kotlin and have run into some behaviour I don't understand.

The following code (using JodaTime) will yield the desired result of 2017-11-24T00:00:00.000Z'

```
val dateTime = DateTime()
val withTimeAtStartOfDay = dateTime
        .minusYears(1)
        .withTimeAtStartOfDay()

println(withTimeAtStartOfDay.toString())
```

To attempt to replicate this in a DSL I created the following function

```
inline fun createUtcDate(block: DateTime.() -> DateTime): String {
    val dateTime = DateTime()
    return dateTime.block().toString()
}
```

Calling this function with the following code yields the result of '2018-11-24T00:00:00.000Z' where, as you can see, only the call to `withTimeAtStartOfDay()` is applied.

```
val utcDate = createUtcDate {
    minusYears(1)
    withTimeAtStartOfDay()
}
println(utcDate)
```

I'm assuming that this is something to do with the chaining of method calls on the DateTime object but don't understand what the issue is. Can someone help?

Comment: Most likely `minusYears(1)` returns a different instance similar to `"hello".replace("o", "o world")` would return a different string instance.

Edit: The documentation confirms this to be the case, it returns a copy with -1 year

Comment: If that's the case, just adding a `.` before the second call should work.

Comment: Thank you both, that does fix the issue.

Comment: From reading your code, the reason this fix works, is because you are acting on the singular object on the last line of code, the other lines need a target.

I'll add my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original look far more legible, and easier to understand. And, if you came back in a month, you would add another line without worry. To accomplish that, all you need is:

```
inline fun createUtcDate(block: DateTime.() -> Unit): String {
    val dateTime = DateTime()
    dateTime.apply(block)
    return dateTime.toString()
}
```